# Fluentbit nested json parsing

Tags: json, parsing, fluent-bit

I have the following log

```json
{
  "log": {
    "header": {
      "key": "value",
      "nested": "{\"key1\":\"value\",\"key2\":\"value\"}",
      "dateTime": "2019-05-08T20:58:06+00:00"
    },
    "body": {
      "path": "/request/path/",
      "method": "POST",
      "ua": "curl/7.54.0",
      "resp": 200
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to aggregate logs using fluentbit and I want the entire record to be JSON. The specific problem is the "log.header.nested" field, which is a JSON string. How can I parse and replace that string with its contents?

I tried using a parser filter from [fluentbit](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/parser). But I have an issue with `key_name` it doesn't work well with nested json values. I tried testing it locally with non nested fields and the following configuration works:

```
[INPUT]
    name             tail
    path             nst.log
    read_from_head   true
    Parser           json
[FILTER]
    name          parser
    Match         *
    Parser        json
    key_name      log
    Reserve_Data  On

[FILTER]
    name          parser
    Match         *
    Parser        json
    key_name      nested
    Reserve_Data  On

[OUTPUT]
    name             stdout
    match            *
```

But when I try this filter for nested values:

```
[FILTER]
    name          parser
    Match         *
    Parser        json
    key_name      log.header.nested
    Reserve_Data  On
```

It doesn't work, there is nothing on fluentbit documentation about how to use nested keys in `key_name` fileds. So I tried:

- `log.header.nested`
- `log_header_nest`
- `log['header']['nest']`
- `log[header][nest]`

For clarity, I'd like the logs output by fluentbit to look like this:

```yaml
{
  "log": {
    "header": {
      "key": "value",
      "nested": {
          "key1": "value",
          "key2": "value"
      },
      "dateTime": "2019-05-08T20:58:06+00:00"
    },
    "body": {
      "path": "/request/path/",
      "method": "POST",
      "ua": "curl/7.54.0",
      "resp": 200
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to combine Nest filter plugin with Parser filter plugin.
For Instance I manage to parse nested json at first level with the following configuration:

```
    [FILTER]
        Name               nest
        Match              application.*
        Operation          lift
        Nested_under       log_processed
        Add_prefix         log_
        Wildcard           message
   [FILTER]
       Name                parser
       Match               application.*
       Key_Name            log_message
       Parser              docker        
       Preserve_Key        On
       Reserve_Data        On
```

Before the two filter the message is:

```
{
  "time": "2022-05-10T19:43:04.655207298Z",
  "stream": "stdout",
  "_p": "F",
  "log": "{\"timestamp\":\"2022-05-10 19:43:04.654\",\"level\":\"DEBUG\",\"nested\":"{\"key1\":\"value\",\"key2\":\"value\"}",\"context\":\"default\"}",
  "log_processed": {
      "timestamp": "2022-05-10 19:43:04.654",
      "level": "DEBUG",     
      "message": "{\"key1\":\"value\",\"key2\":\"value\"}",
      "context": "default"
   }
 }
```

after the two filter the one level nested json was parsed to:

```
{
  "time": "2022-05-10T19:43:04.655207298Z",
  "stream": "stdout",
  "_p": "F",
  "log": "{\"timestamp\":\"2022-05-10 19:43:04.654\",\"level\":\"DEBUG\",\"nested\":"{\"key1\":\"value\",\"key2\":\"value\"}",\"context\":\"default\"}",
  "log_processed": {
      "timestamp": "2022-05-10 19:43:04.654",
      "level": "DEBUG",     
      "message": "{\"key1\":\"value\",\"key2\":\"value\"}",
      "context": "default"
   },
 log_message: "{\"key1\":\"value\",\"key2\":\"value\"}".
 "key1" : "value",
 "key2" : "value"
}
```

You could try to apply nest plugin with lift operation more than once.